# Using imageButtons to switch activities. How can I switch image in second activity based on button pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am just starting to dabble with Android development. Right now, I have a program in Android Studio that has two columns of images about 6 images each. I want to make it so if I click that image, it will appear in the new activity. Right now, I am just loading the layout like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra(Main.CHAMPION_NAME);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_champion_page);

}
```

With the layout in setContentView looking like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="atree496.leaguestats.ChampionPage">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/azir"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As of now, it opens to the one image because that is how it is set up, but I want to be able to have the image be the one that I click. What changes do I need to do in order to achieve this? Again, I am new to this. Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

You could add to the intent the int resource of your pressed image if you give it file name to Tag attribute in xml:

```
ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/azir"
android:tag="theImageFileName.png"
android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```

Then you could retreive it when pressed and add it to the Intent you are using:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     String fileName = (String) v.getTag();
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("fileName", fileName);
      startActivity(intent);
 }
```

In second activity after you initialize the secondImageView:

```
String fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("fileName");
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(fileName,"drawable", getPackageName());
secondImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resId));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just have a question about the last section. Do you mean to put that in the xml file or the java file?

Comment: Waht your choice. I would put it in XML without  the src attribute. If my answer help you I will appreciate if you would accept it.

Comment: I would, but I still haven't been able to get the code to work. Is the secondImage the imageView in the second XML? This is what my program looks like in use. http://imgur.com/a/ndZm5

If I click, on the image, I want it to appear in the new activity, so there are two activities and two XML files. There will only be one image on the second activity. That is why I am confused as to where to put in the last part. How can I use that info in the XML file when it is first assigned in the java file for the activity?

Comment: Look, you put in the xml of the second Activity the widgets you want there. If you want just 1 ImageView so put 1 ImageView and use the code I gave you to populate it.