# How to send ImageViews to another activity in android

Tags: android

I have implemented the single tap and double tap on imageviews in my application and I want to send these images to another activity on a single tap or double tap how should I do it?

Comment: where do you have your images stored

Comment: Just pass the path or Uri to the bitmap as a `String` extra of the `Intent` used to start the second `Activity`.

Comment: I have the images in the drawable file

Comment: is this the code @Squonk :  Uri imageuri=Uri.parse("android.resource//com.example.and1/drawable/"+R.drawable.fw);
         
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageuri);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send images to another activity, you are actually sending `Bitmap` or `Drawable` objects.

First, u can use a *global variable* to store the Bitmap. Them just save bitmap to the variable in one activity and get it from another activity.

Second, u may use a `Bundle`.

On `OneActivity`:

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("img",yourBitmap);//put your bitmap in
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setClass(OneActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);  
intent.putExtras(b);
```

On `AnotherActivity`'s onCreate:

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap = (Bitmap)b.getParcelable("img");
```

Hope you get it!

Comment: I using drawables. do I have to convert it to bitmap?

Comment: @user4672418 no. You only need to replace the `Bitmap` of my codes with `Drawable`

Comment: Drawable objects are not inherently serializable.

Comment: Anyway it is not a good practice to deliver resources inside Intent.

Comment: I have tried this code but when I click on the button it says the application has stopped working:    Bundle b1=new Bundle();
         
         Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.fw);
        
         
        b1.putParcelable("img",bitmap);//put your bitmap in
        Intent intent = new Intent();  
        int id=R.drawable.fw;
         
        intent.putExtras(b1);

Comment: @user4672418 Er, if you really use a bitmap from resource, please put int instead of bitmap.

Comment: when I am replacing the bitmap code in b.putParcelable  I have to put R.drawable.fw;

Comment: where do I have to put the int?

Comment: @user4672418 no. Use `putInt` for int putting.

Answer (score 0):

If your source to those images is inside your project (like drawable folder) you could add the file name String as tag inside xml and add it via EXTRA to your intent. Here little example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021448/3332634

Comment: it doesnot work. it gives this error when I click the images "application has stopped"

Comment: What I want to do is on a single tap or double tap the image is sent to the enxt activity and when I click on a button it goes to the other activity with the images displayed.

Comment: But you say you got error. What exactly was the error in Logcat?

Comment: in whice line? copy the line that generate it

Comment: Actually right now I am trying this code                                                                      Bundle b1=new Bundle();
         
         Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.fw);
        
         
        b1.putParcelable("img",bitmap);//put your bitmap in
        Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.putExtras(b1);

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
: E/AndroidRuntime(944): Process: com.example.and1, 
 E/AndroidRuntime(944): java.lang.NullPointerException
: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at com.example.$1.onSingleTapConfirmed
: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:273)
03-15 07:00:27.660: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-15 07:00:27.660: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-15 07:00:27.660: E/AndroidRuntime(944):

Comment: I don't know what is your 944, what generate the NullPoint?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you.

There is this method for imageview

```
 setImageResource(int resId)
```

So in your first activity store it like this

```
    int yourid=R.drawable.yourimage
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,yourotheractivityname.class)
    intent.putInt("key",resId)
```

In your other activity

```
    Intent intent=getIntent()
    int yourid=intent.getExtras().getInt("key")
    yourImageView.setImageResource(yourId)
```

Comment: What I want to do is that on single tap the image is sent to the next activity.and when I click on a button it goes to that activity

Comment: ok when you go to that activity with something like startActivity(intent) 
before that say intent.putInt("key", id)

Comment: Then in my next activity how do I get it